# Exempt Static Assets from Authorization in .NET Core 3 SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have a SPA running on .NET Core 3.1. I followed the steps on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization) to secure static assets in a folder outside of my wwwroot folder, but (predictably) adding

```
services.AddAuthorization(opts => { 
    opts.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build(); 
});
```

in my Startup blocks access to the SPA source files inside ClientApp/build (and thus my app doesn't work).

My question is: how can I allow public access (i.e. skip checking the authorization policy) for additional folders (besides just wwwroot)? The article notes that `UseStaticFiles()` allows `wwwroot` to be publicly accessible (by checking the `WebRootFileProvider` in the `IWebHostEnvironment`), but only a single value can be configured to that property. I'd like to avoid moving the entire SPA app into wwwroot, but maybe that is the only solution?

Comment: Perhaps with the [`CompositeFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0#composite-file-provider)?

Comment: Interesting, so that could be used to combine the wwwroot folder provider with a provider for the SPA folder and override the default fileprovider in the IWebRootHost?

Comment: `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` is settable, so I think it's worth a try

Comment: I was able to set `env.WebRootFileProvider` with: 
`var defaultProvider = env.WebRootFileProvider;`
`var spaFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp", "build"));`
`env.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(defaultProvider, spaFileProvider);`

but same results. Looking more at `StaticFileMiddleware` (provided by `UseStaticFiles()`) I'm not seeing anything that explicitly surpasses authorization for WebRoot, so thinking the issue may be in `AddAuthorization`

Comment: Why would you want to create a separate folder if you were going to make it public - why not just make it a folder under wwwroot?

Comment: Partially out of curiosity (it seems I should be able to make other folders publicly accessible / exempt from authorization requirements) and otherwise because I assume there's a reason ClientApp by default is not in wwwroot (in the app templates). If it's best practice to place all public assets in wwwroot I won't sweat it too much.

Comment: @broccoli_rob, you can use `new DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider().GetFallbackPolicyAsync()`